# Can't open a file and write a simple string into it

Tags: ruby

I get an error when I run this code:

```
File.open(File.join(SOME_TEMP_DIR, "hello.txt"), "w") { |f| f.puts("hello") }
# => Failure/Error: File.open(File.join(SOME_TEMP_DIR, "hello.txt"), "w") { |f| f.puts("hello") }
# => Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /home/PATH_TO_MY_SOME_TEMP_DIR/hello.txt
```

Why doesn't it create a `hello.txt` file? The permission for the directory is: `drwxrwxr-x` 
I am running my code in my spec file, inside Rails.

Comment: Directory already exists

Comment: If you run `File.exists?(SOME_TEMP_DIR)` does it return true?

Comment: When I open folders in my file system, my eyes says `true` ;) Anyway, I have re-run the test for the 10th time, and without any modification it said that the directory exists now :o in anycase, it helped to try to re run few more times :) thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `SOME_TEMP_DIR` does not exist.

I've run variations of your code in `irb`, and I get the same error if my `SOME_TEMP_DIR` parameter doesn't equate to an existing directory.  If I create the directory and run it again, it works.

Comment: Hmm, like all the strange things, after re-running the same test without any changes the test passed. The file was created and the directory did exist. Hm. I don't know why. But in any case, this is the closes answer ;) and it helped me to try to re-run the test again (even though I have run it few times so far). Thanks